# Problems extending `format-string` with HH24MISS when converting decimal column based timestamp to actual timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

## tl;dr

Why am I not able to convert following string timestamp

```
select timestamp_format('2015-08-21 000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24MISS') as timestamp
  from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

on an i7.1.0/OS machine?

Especially since I can convert

```
select timestamp_format('000000' , 'HH24MISS') as timestamp
  from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

to:

```
timestamp
-------------------------
2015-08-01 00:00:00.000000
```

## Context

On an i7.1.0/OS machine, I have a table with timestamp data split up in several decimal columns, like

```
declare global temporary table tstamp
(
  year dec(4,0),
  month dec(2,0),
  day dec(2,0),
  time dec(6,0)
);
```

with data like

```
insert into session.tstamp
  values (2015,8,21,92601),
         (2015,8,21,132601);
```

on which I want to do some date filtering. Given the somewhat inflexible format, I figured that it is probably better if I convert this to a timestamp and use this to query the table. So i consulted the [i/OS 7.1 Manual on `timestamp_format`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm)

I started of with building the date part, ending up with

```
select
  timestamp_format(YEAR || '-' || MONTH || '-' || DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as timestamp
  from session.tstamp;
```

which returns

```
TIMESTAMP
--------------------------
2015-08-21 00:00:00.000000  
2015-08-21 00:00:00.000000
```

Perfect, let us add the time part and explicit `lpad` it to contain six characters:

```
select
  timestamp_format(YEAR || '-' || MONTH || '-' || DAY || ' ' || lpad(TIME, 6, '0'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24MISS') as timestamp
  from session.tstamp;
```

This results in the following error:

> SQL State: 22007
>
> Vendor Code: -20448
>
> Message: [SQ20448] Expression not valid using format string specified for TIMESTAMP_FORMAT. Cause . . . . . :   Argument 1 of the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function can not be interpreted using the format string specified in argument 2 for one of the following reasons: -- The string expression is too short or too long. -- The string expression does not conform to the template specified in the format string. -- Too many digits were specified in the string expression for the corresponding format element in the format string. -- A value in the string expression is not valid for the corresponding format element in the format string. Recovery  . . . :   Specify a valid format string for the function. Try the request again.

According to the [manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm) regarding the `format-string`, a separator between fields is optional:

> [...]
>   Two format elements can optionally be separated by one or more of the following separator characters:
>   [...]

### Question

So why are not my values accepted when using 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24MISS' as the `format-string`, given that I explicit has bound the time length to six characters?

#### Side note

It is possible to use `HH24MISS` on its own as `format-string`, so I'm not really able to wrap my head around this.

```
select timestamp_format(lpad(TIME, 6, '0'), 'HH24MISS') as timestamp from session.tstamp;

TIMESTAMP
--------------------------
2015-08-01 13:26:01.000000  
2015-08-01 09:26:01.000000
```

Comment: ...It would be better to be storing it as a timestamp to begin with, although you may not be able to change that now.  Save you a lot of headaches with queries and invalid values, though (at least one potential workaround here may not be DST safe).  Note that translating to timestamp for a `WHERE` clause will make the query non-SARGable; it won't be able to use an index (applies to pretty much every function).  What happens if you leave out more of the separators?

Comment: I totally agree with you about the architectural concerns of the pros with having it in a timestamp field. The In this case, the queries will be used to fetch test data. So speed is not the biggest concern.

Leaving out all separators works as expected, but that forces me to left pad all fields instead. But you are definitely on something here; I get the same error if I just have the space as sole separator.

Comment: Yeah, I think that, contrary to what's implied in the documentation, you either need to separate everything or nothing.

Comment: It does work as expected in i/OS 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulties described, are due to defects with the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT [aka TO_DATE] scalar. The requests shown are tested to have functioned, as expected, with the DB2 for IBM i 7.3 [and as a comment to the OP suggests, also on v7r2]. I had asked a similar question, "Why the failures using my earlier examples?" in [SQL convert text mm/dd/yy to date and timestamp](http://archive.midrange.com/midrange-l/201607/msg00172.html), but I have not yet re-visited those examples on the newer release.  And FWiW, there may be some updated code on IBM i 7.1 for that feature with the latest code; I do not have that level of maintenance, so I can not test if the [the last of the] enhancements that are coming for that release include the code fixes that apparently exist in newer releases.

Note that the TO_DATE feature is not a true built-in [instead, is a system-supplied User Defined Function (UDF)], so personally, I would recommend an alternative; namely, writing and using a scalar UDF specific to the task, and/or choose a more compatible and easy way to generate the TIMESTAMP from those columns as they are defined.  Consider the following expression [that assumes all dates are beyond year 1000, else the expression must change to use DIGITS(YEAR) vs just YEAR]:

```
timestamp( YEAR concat digits( MONTH ) concat digits( DAY )
           concat digits( TIME )
         )
```

A variation of that, is to use arithmetic to achieve the same effect of a [14–character timestamp-string form 'yyyymmddhhmmss'](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafztsstrings.htm):

```
timestamp( concat( YEAR * 10000  + MONTH * 100 + DAY
                 , digits ( TIME ) ) )
```

The following scalar function could be created to avoid coding the expression in [VIEW] queries or other places.  As coded, with nothing but an expression on a RETURN statement, should allow *in-lining*; I did not specify any other potentially performance-related clauses such as parallel or on-null-input:

```
create function y4m2d2t6TS                   
( year   dec(4, 0)                           
, month  dec(2, 0)                           
, day    dec(2, 0)                           
, time   dec(6, 0)                           
) returns timestamp                          
language sql deterministic                   
return                                       
   digits( YEAR ) concat digits( MONTH )     
   concat digits( DAY ) concat digits( TIME )

; -- this semicolon is a statement separator, not terminator of above CREATE
select 
  y4m2d2t6TS( year, month, day, time ) as timestamp
from session.tstamp
; -- likeness of report from above query:
TIMESTAMP                 
2015-08-21-09.26.01.000000
2015-08-21-13.26.01.000000
********  End of data  ***
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in DB2 :

```
values(VARCHAR_FORMAT(current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Bye

Comment: How is this supposed to help me? The first parameter is an actual timestamp and this is not what I have available. I want to create that actual timestamp.

Comment: If you just want the actual timestamp in special format . replace the current_date in the code with your timestamp . and change the param 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' . Or give me exemple what you want IN and OUT .